# Android singleline texthint

Tags: android

The setHint and singleLine settings don't seem to be able to work
together. If my hint is longer than a single line and I have
singleLine set to true, the editText box automatically spans to 2
lines regardless.

Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: hint to use just to intimate something. why do you explaining  it lengthily.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do:

```
textView.setHint("Veeeeeery looooooong hiiiiiiint");
textView.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
textView.setSingleLine();
```

and it seems to work. The hint is truncated with ellipsize at the end.